# How to show that an analytic function can be written as $g(z)^k$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function with $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f \neq 0$. Let $k = gr(f, z_0) \geq 1$. Show that there exists an analytic function $g$ such that locally, $g(z)^k = f(z)$.

I know that if $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$, then i could let $h$ be the antiderivative of $f'/f$, so that $f(z)e^{-h(z)}$ is a constant, and finally write $f$ as $f(z) = ce^{h(z)}$, and then lastly, i could let $g(z) = c^{1/k}e^{h(z)/k}$

But this technique doesn't work in this case, since f can't be written as $e^{h(z)}$.

How should i go on about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Write $\frac{f(z)}{z^k} = e^{h(z)}$ for instance.

Comment: Looking at $f'/f$ and $\log f$ works even if $f$ has some zeros, just replace $f$ by $f/P_r$ where $P_r$ is a polynomial containing its zeros on $|z-z_0| < r$. You'll find that $f(z)^{1/k}$ is analytic on $|z-z_0| < r$ iff all the zeros are of order $mk$.

Comment: Please explain the terms in the first paragraph, like what $f\ne 0$ means, and what $gr(f,z_0) $ means.

Comment: I'm also curious about the terms @zhw mentioned. Could you explain what they mean?

Comment: @Cary yes sure. f != 0 means that f is not the constant function 0. And gr(f, z_0) mean that when writing f in its taylor series, f(z) = a_0 + a_1x^n + ..., all of a_1, ..., a_{k-1} are zero and a_k is not zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i managed to solve it.

Since $f$ is analytic, it can be written as

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n (z - z_0)^n$$

And because $gr(f, z_0) = k$ we have that

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} a_n (z - z_0)^n$$

$$ = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n+ k} (z - z_0)^{n+k}$$

$$ = (z - z_0)^{k} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n+ k} (z - z_0)^{n}$$

$$ = (z - z_0)^{k} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_{n} (z - z_0)^{n}$$

where $b_n = a_{n+k}$. Let us name this new function as $r(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} b_{n} (z - z_0)^{n}$. Now, since $b_0 = a_k \neq 0$, we have that $r(z_0) \neq 0$.

$r$ is clearly analytic, and since it is not $0$, then $\frac{r'}{r}$ is analytic. Let $h$ be it's antiderivative.

Now, notice that

$$(r(z)e^{-h(z)})' = r'(z)e^{-h(z)} - r(z)e^{-h(z)}h'(z) =r'(z)e^{-h(z)} - r(z)e^{-h(z)}\frac{r'(z)}{r(z)} = 0$$

Therefore, $r(z)e^{-h(z)} = c$, and we conclude that $r(z) = ce^{h(z)}$.

Replacing this in the expression of $f$ we conclude that

$f(z) = (z - z_0)^kce^{h(z)}$. Now writing $g(z) = (z - z_0)c^{1/k}e^{\frac{h(z)}{k}}$, we can see that $g(z)^k = f(z)$

Comment: I think this works. Is there a mistake here?

Comment: You give an answer to your own question after $30$ minutes?

Comment: @zhw I read orangeskid comment and tried it this way. Do you have a problem with this?

Comment: I have a problem with askers of questions answering their own questions so quickly. But fine, maybe I'm alone on this.